# split url in url and path, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, url, path, split

i have an application where users submit URL's. these urls may be anything, a few examples are here:

```
ftp://ftp.mysite.com
ftp.mysiste.com
mysite.com
mysite.de
ftp.mysite.it/somepath/somotherfolder
ftp://ftp.anysiste.com/
ftp://ftp.anysiste.org/somefolder/
```

i need to split these sites in the URL and the PATH. here is the result of the above:

```
ftp.mysite.com ---- /
ftp.mysiste.com ---- /
mysite.com ---- /
mysite.de ---- /
ftp.mysite.it ---- /somepath/somotherfolder
ftp.anysiste.com ---- /
ftp.anysiste.org ---- /somefolder/
```

is there a safe way to split these like this? or do i have to make it via search/split functions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `System.Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx).

```
Dim uri As New Uri("ftp://ftp.anysiste.org/somefolder/")
uri.AbsolutePath '/somefolder/
uri.Host         'ftp.anysiste.org
uri.Scheme       'ftp
```

Comment: @Justme: That’s considered a relative path unless you actually give it a protocol. What should it be assumed to be? FTP? HTTP?

Comment: always FTP.. any url is Always an FTP path since files have to be uploaded there.

Comment: @Justme: `If Not url.StartsWith("ftp://") Then url = "ftp://" & url` before `New Uri(url)`, I suppose…

Comment: Don't forget that this is a case sensitive comparison. You might end up with something like `ftp://FTP://...`.